# Closing an EDM ObjectContext?

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting started with the ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.0. I have created an EDM and data store for the app, and it successfully retrieves entities. The application holds the EDM's `ObjectContext` as a member-level variable, which it uses to call `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()`. So far, so good.

I am going to refactor to repositories later. Right now, my question is a bit more basic: When I am finished with the EDM, what do I need to do to release it? Is it as simple as calling `Dispose()` on the `ObjectContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, calling dispose on the ObjectContext is sufficient to dispose of the resources.